# call RPGLE program from SQL within PHP / Zend Framework

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, call, ibm-midrange

We have an AS400 RPGLE program created within the library LMTLIB, which is called ARTEST.

It has a single numeric inout parameter, which just returns    2

```
$myVar = "1";

$db = Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->multidb->as400;

$abstractAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Db2($db);

//Gives the message "Invalid bind-variable position 'myVar'"
$sql = 'CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC(\'CALL LMTLIB.ARTEST PARM(?)\', 0000000026.00000)';

//Gives the message "Token PARM was not valid. Valid tokens: ( INTO USING. SQLCODE=-104"    
$sql = 'CALL LMTLIB.ARTEST PARM(?)';

//Gives the message "ARTEST in LMTLIB type *N not found. SQLCODE=-204"
$sql = 'CALL LMTLIB.ARTEST (?)';

$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Db2($abstractAdapter, $sql);

$stmt->bindParam('myVar', $myVar, 4, 1);

$stmt->execute();
```

Now, i can kind-of understand why the third SQL statement would fail with the "not found" message... because it is not a table / file, but rather an RPGLE program.

The thing thats irritating, is that if i remove the (?), and simply put in (1)... the SQL call appears to be successful, and the RPGLE program shows it had been called.  However, I'm then not able to see what the response from the program was.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the database manager uses the CALL statement to invoke a stored procedure.  When it does that, it looks for a stored proc whose parameter signature matches the signature of the CALL.

If there's no stored proc with that name and signature, the database manager tries to call a program.  Again, there's a parameter matching process that happens.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/db2/rbafzmstcallsta.htm

I suggest creating a stored procedure so you can get the parameters matched properly.

Comment: Look's like it works with Zend. Just one piece of advise: when I worked with php and odbc on a db2/400, i had to find out that php_odbc does not support output parameters.

Answer (score 1):

IBM RPGLE can interface with the Zend framework through webservice calls.

Scott Klement goes over some of the basics of this [here.](https://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Web%20Services%20for%20RPGers.pdf)

Depending on your application, this may be the best way to interface with RPG code.  Webservices can be made to call many RPG programs and iSeries tables, and return a catered result set.  Zend would see this the same as any other RESTful call, which could be handled by your models.